# About : Failed to read the 'result' property from 'IDBRequest'

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a function to fetch currently login-ing user's data. Confusingly, the open request didn't call any callbacks. This is really annoying and has to be resolved.

```
export async function getCurrUser(window) {
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
        let currUserAcc='curuser',//the currently login-ing user
            openRequest = indexedDB.open('userData',2);/*this line didnt call any callbacks bellow. why?*/

        openRequest.onsuccess =  e => {
            let db = e.target.result;
            try{
                //access users and shops tables in indexeddb
                let transaction= db.transaction(['users','shops'],'readwrite');
                let objStore=  transaction.objectStore('users'), req= objStore.get('curuser');
                //callbacks handling req
                ...
            } catch (e) {db.close();}
        }
        openRequest.onupgradeneeded =  e => {
            //create the indexeddb
            let db = e.target.result;
            if(db) {
                //create users and shops tables
                db.close();
            }
        }
        openRequest.onerror=e=> {/*this does printings. but it didnt come here.*/}
    });

}
```

So, I printed out the openrequest. It looks like this.
[image]

Although in the result 'Exception' shows, I used try-catch and nothing was caught.
Is it possible to get the result under this situation?

When this issue occurred, I observed from the chrome inspector and saw something like
[image]

No versions (loading seemed stuck). But the db still exists.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: I can't seem to replicate this issue. The exact code works for me in Chrome. Although logging `IDBOpenDBRequest` before the request finishes does give the exact object as shown in your image sample. Have you tried executing this code in another browser?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The codes work fine most of the time, This issue occurs for the first time today under a certain situation. I added more details in my post.

Comment: Please do elaborate the "certain situation". If this exact code you have given actually works, then it is impossible for us to find out the real problem.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBRequest/readyState
Maybe I can setup a timer for the .open function code, and if the readyState is still pending, this operation can be identified as invalid?